# analyzing transaction cost for a smart contract

Tags: solidity, web3js

Given a smart contract, How do I figure out the total amount of gas used? 
Say for example a smart contract which has a parameterized constructor which stores 5 variables which are address type variables, passed in the parameter of a function. What would be the amount of gas this function uses?

also, whoever uses the smart contract can give their choice of gas cost?

Answer (score 1):

Each operation in the EVM costs gas. Different operations cost different amount of gas - you can read more for example here: https://hackernoon.com/ether-purchase-power-df40a38c5a2f (and its references). I'm not too familiar with the opcodes so I can't tell you how much storing 5 addresses would exactly cost.

Clients typically provide you with a gas estimate when you are about to send a transaction. Often this is an accurate estimate but sometimes it's impossible to estimate it properly.

Whoever sends a transaction to a contract can decide the *gas price*. The higher price you give the faster miners will probably include you transaction in a block but also the more Ether the transaction costs for you.

Answer (score 0):

Transaction execution is based on accounting for the OPCODES executed and the price list.

> Say for example a smart contract which has a parameterized constructor which stores 5 variables

The actual deployment cost is the gas consumed by the deployment transaction. Like any other kind of transaction, it can be run in "dry-run" to estimate that cost (this is what most wallets do) but the authoritative cost is the transaction cost recorded on the chain.

> whoever uses the smart contract can give their choice of gas cost?

Yes, wallets can estimate gas by running the function. This will give an estimate of gas consumption. `gasPrice` is a multiplier that prioritizes the transaction in the eyes of the miners. Total cost is `gas * gasPrice` in ETH which can then be converted to currency. It's all about what you mean by "cost."

> How do I figure out

You figure it out by running the function. The [halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) basically states that there is nothing you can construct to feed arbitrary software and variables to work out will happen that is better than actually running the software to find out. Any sort of estimation process has to be fitted to the program to test and, therefore, wouldn't be general-purpose.

Gas estimation is usually done by running the transaction in a hypothetical, read-only manner to collect the accounting of the total gas that *would have been* consumed. It usually works but it has inherent limitations. It cannot account for changes in the logic (if, for, while) that will result from state changes that might occur before the transaction is actually mined.

In other words, if the initial conditions when the transaction is mined differ from the initial conditions when the estimate was computed then the *logic* inside the function might do different things. Developers try to minimize variations in the cost of doing things but it may be necessary for a UI to estimate gas itself, add a little safety margin and inform the wallet rather than relying exclusively on the automatic estimation.

For example, consider a simple algo that awards a prize to the 100th customer. Let us assume that there is extra work to do when the 100th customer receives the prize - to award the prize. Rehearsing the transaction wouldn't catch it, especially if lots of people are racing to send 100th transaction *but none actually are* when the transaction cost is estimated. A developer might want to make sure a little extra gas is sent to ensure that there is enough on hand to get it done when the lucky winner arrives.

Hope it helps.